# Populate Javascript Array with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am attempting to load a large set of JSON files into an array to be referenced later but Node keeps stating they're undefined. I have code along the lines of:

```
var myarray = [];

(...)

var loading_num = 001; // will be incremented in a loop to load data
myarray[loading_num] = fs.readFileSync("data/" + loading_num);

(...)

var reference_num = "001"; // the number being used to pull the appropriate record

(...)

console.log(myarray[reference_num].name); // just testing to attempt to decipher why it doesn't work, I'll actually be using the data obviously
```

Each JSON file does have a value named `name` and I have not implemented logic to load all of them yet as I am still just trying to get one to work.

Am I misunderstading something about Javascript arrays or objects? What am I doing wrong? There's a lot of files and they can vary in number so I have to load them in some similar fashion.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(myarray[loading_num].name);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. `fs.readFileSync` reads arbitrary files. If you know your file is JSON and you want to convert it to js you need to parse it using `JSON.parse`.

Then `001` is `1` if you want it to be a string wrap it with quotes `'001'`

Array indices starts from 0.

```
var myarray = [];
myarray.push(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data/001")));
console.log(myarray[0].name);
```

Or

```
var myarray = {}; // use object
myarray['001'] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data/001"));
var reference_num = "001";
console.log(myarray[reference_num].name);
```

Comment: That second example is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I do have to reference using the leading zeroes and I didn't know it had to run through JSON.parse if it was already a JSON formatted file though I suppose that makes sense when I think about it, the program doesn't know any better. Thank you

Comment: Why not just `require` the JSON file?

Comment: @torazaburo require will put entire file contents in its cache. This might have undesired effects. You'll need to manually delete contents from cache if you decide to reread file from disk due to some external changes. It will prevent garbage collection which is not what you want if you need only some projections of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the file contents so the raw data is converted into JavaScript objects.

```js
myarray[001] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data/001"));
```

Comment: You failed to give the best answer which is to `require` the JSON file.

Comment: I've seen WRONG answers with several upvotes.  I gave the first correct answer, focusing on the one line that was the source of the only error the question focused on, and someone built up on it.  If giving a CORRECT but less wordy answer gets downvotes, but giving WORDY INCORRECT answers get upvotes, then I'd rather not try.

Comment: @undetected Just to be clear. Your answer was the second. It adds nothing to mine and still contains some errors :) Though I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko When I typed my answer, yours wasn't there yet.  If it was, I wouldn't have given a comparatively shorter one.  Between yours and mine, I would upvote yours.

Comment: To settle this, you both submited an answer at nearly the same time and were likely typing the answers up simultaneously. I was watching the question as it was very close after I created it. I do want to thank you undetected for the answer, it does solve my problem, but I chose Yurys answer as it had two solutions and the second also aided in a separate issue (the reference numbers needing leading zeroes) that would have cropped up after. I also chose his answer because anyone coming here in the future are given two solutions that could help in varying circumstances.